# Deploying asp.net web application on IIS version 8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I'm running an application on local machine as http://localhost . Everything works fine. When deploying on iis8.5 I have to add virtual path, i.e. myApp. Now when running the app the address becomes: http://ip address/myApp. Now images, and other files will not load.

How can I avoid myApp from the virtual path which is entered as alias I believe.

Comment: Please don't use relative url path in the image url.  Try use the `~` sign to get the right url of your image.  e.g.  `<img src="~/images/test.png">`

Comment: Is there any way I can run my app without alias in virtual path. like typing www.mydomain.com then landing on the first page?

Comment: Sure!  Please let me know how you deploy your website now?

Comment: I ended up deploying on the root folder, not under default websites.